# How to use Zend Framework 1 when is installed through composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Recently I discovered that Zend Framework 1 (ZF1) can be installed using `composer` so I did a: `composer require zendframework/zendframework1`. That change my `composer.json` by adding the following:

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": ["application/models", "application/controllers", "application/forms"]},
    "psr-4": { "": ["src/", "library/"]}
  },
  "require": {
     ...
    "zendframework/zendframework1": "^1.12"
  }
}
```

After run the command `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` I look into the composer generated files and I can see the following:

```
/vendor/composer/autoload_files.php
===================================
// autoload_files.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    '92c8763cd6170fce6fcfe7e26b4e8c10' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php',
    '0e6d7bf4a5811bfa5cf40c5ccd6fae6a' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php',
    'c964ee0ededf28c96ebd9db5099ef910' => $vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php',
    'a0edc8309cc5e1d60e3047b5df6b7052' => $vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php',
    '2c102faa651ef8ea5874edb585946bce' => $vendorDir . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php',
    'b067bc7112e384b61c701452d53a14a8' => $vendorDir . '/mtdowling/jmespath.php/src/JmesPath.php',
    '37a3dc5111fe8f707ab4c132ef1dbc62' => $vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php',
    '8a9dc1de0ca7e01f3e08231539562f61' => $vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php',
    '5255c38a0faeba867671b61dfda6d864' => $vendorDir . '/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php',
    '023d27dca8066ef29e6739335ea73bad' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php',
    'bd9634f2d41831496de0d3dfe4c94881' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php56/bootstrap.php',
    '6a47392539ca2329373e0d33e1dba053' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-intl-icu/bootstrap.php',
    '32dcc8afd4335739640db7d200c1971d' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-apcu/bootstrap.php',
    '3a37ebac017bc098e9a86b35401e7a68' => $vendorDir . '/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php',
);

/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
===================================
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend_' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework1/library'),
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'SensioLabs\\Security' => array($vendorDir . '/sensiolabs/security-checker'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    '' => array($baseDir . '/application/models', $baseDir . '/application/controllers', $baseDir . '/application/forms'),
);

/vendor/composer/include_paths.php
===================================
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework1/library',
);
```

I am trying to use then the class from the `application/bootstrap.php` file as for example:

```
use Zend_Config_Ini;
$config   = new Zend_Config_Ini('./../config/config.ini', 'general');
```

But PHP is complaining with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Config_Ini' not found in
>   /var/www/html/application/bootstrap.php:23

Why? What I am missing here?

Comment: There is another package for the config https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-config is it possible that you need that and the class is not in your config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That are [composer basics](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), you need to include the autoloader file to be able to load those classes.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```